# What's the correct way in making an iOS 9 app backward compatible with iOS 6?

Tags: ios, diawi

I am trying to create a simple webview. The person wants it to run on devices starting with iOS 6.  I've set iOS Deployment Target at 6.1 and my base SDK is 9.3. I have it code-signed, provisions, etc.

I used a program called Deploymate to check if any conflicts would exist across the iOS versions. It passed.

I uploaded the IPA to Diawi. However, it crashes on my device (iOS 9) and says it "Could not be installed at this time". The simulator had no problems.

Is there anyway to diagnose this problem or have I skipped a step? I've seen other questions, but they pertain to iOS 7.

Comment: What's the console log on the device when you try to install it. That should give a hint.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about the console log. Here is what came up: " is authorized by a free provisioning profile, but apps validated by those are not allowed to be installed from this source. "

Comment: You can not distribute builds to other devices with the free account. You need to get a paid Apple developer account for that.

Comment: OK, thank you. I believe I got confused because I was looking at stuff pre iOS 9, when it was possible. So even if my client has an active developer's account, there's nothing I can do?

Comment: The app build needs to be signed and provisioned using a paid developer account to be able to share it with other provisioned devices. Check the Ad-Hoc distribution documentation or Testflight.

Comment: OK, I fully understand now. Thank you for taking the time to explain it.